# Spring boot cache css and js

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use spring boot 3 and thymeleaf

I would like to cache css, js and img

```java
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/js/**", "/resources/css/**", "/resources/img/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/js/", "/resources/css/", "/resources/img/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS));
    }
}
```

I tried with

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
```

but get a 404

only

```java
@Configuration
```

doesn't cache

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try something like this?

```java
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter webConfigurer () {
          return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
              @Override
              public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                  registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/js/**")
                          .addResourceLocations("/resources/js/")
                          .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS));
                  registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/img/**")
                  .addResourceLocations("/resources/img/")
                  .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS));
                  registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/css/**")
                  .addResourceLocations("/resources/css/")
                  .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS));
              }
          };
    }
```

Also, recent versions of  SpringBoot has certain `properties` for managing this:

```
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.cache-private= # Indicate that the response message is intended for a single user and must not be stored by a shared cache.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.cache-public= # Indicate that any cache may store the response.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.max-age= # Maximum time the response should be cached, in seconds if no duration suffix is not specified.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.must-revalidate= # Indicate that once it has become stale, a cache must not use the response without re-validating it with the server.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-cache= # Indicate that the cached response can be reused only if re-validated with the server.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-store= # Indicate to not cache the response in any case.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-transform= # Indicate intermediaries (caches and others) that they should not transform the response content.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.proxy-revalidate= # Same meaning as the "must-revalidate" directive, except that it does not apply to private caches.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.s-max-age= # Maximum time the response should be cached by shared caches, in seconds if no duration suffix is not specified.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.stale-if-error= # Maximum time the response may be used when errors are encountered, in seconds if no duration suffix is not specified.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.stale-while-revalidate= # Maximum time the response can be served after it becomes stale, in seconds if no duration suffix is not specified.
```

You may try using any of the above `properties` to achieve your solution.

Comment: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter don't exist anymore